# What is the formal definition in first order logic of the informal statement $\exists x \in A : Qx$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

**tl;dr:** Is the right translation of the informal statement $ \exists x \in A:Q(x)$ into **formal** FOL $\exists x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$? Or $\lor_{x \in A} Qx$? Are they equivalent? Or perhaps something else?

---

My thoughts:

I was reading stuff about [vacuous truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) and noticed the bullet points:

1. $\forall x:P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$, where it is the case that ${\displaystyle \forall x:\neg P(x)} \forall x:\neg P(x)$.
2. ${\displaystyle \forall x\in A:Q(x)} \forall x\in A:Q(x)$, where the set {\displaystyle A} A is empty.
3. ${\displaystyle \forall \xi :Q(\xi )} \forall \xi :Q(\xi )$, where the symbol ${\displaystyle \xi } $  is restricted to a type that has no representatives.

from bullet point 2 I assume that statements of the form $\forall a \in A: Qx$ are translated to $\forall x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$ where $\varphi^A$ is the L-formula that returns True for elements of $A$ (so we are assuming the set A is definable). These is the formal language of L-structures and FOL [according to these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf). However I noticed that if we thought about this algorithmically we could also write the code for $\sigma_{\forall} = \forall x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$ as follows:

```
def translation_of_informal_for_all_statement():
sigma_for_all = True //like this to make code elegant but I dont get it
for a in A:
    sigma_for_all = sigma_for_all && Qx
return sigma_for_all
```

this seems to return the right things for $\forall a \in A: Qx$ and seems identical to $\sigma_{\forall} = \forall x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$ as far as I can tell (i.e. has the same truth table). Especially in the tricky edge case when the set $A$ is empty (which I'm not actually true why it should be true in that case except that if I do set it true it makes the code/algorithm more elegant and compact without weird edge case scenario conditionals in the code). Note the code just expresses the formula $\land_{x \in A} Qx$.

Thus, I wondered what would be the correct (sound, consistent?) translation for $\exists x \in A : Qx$. I thought it would be $\sigma_{\exists} = \exists x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$ just from looking at how the forall statement was translated (just a guess). However it makes sense to me that the code for it should be easy to translate:

```
def translation_of_informal_exists_statement():
sigma_exists = False // like this because no element as of yet satisfies the existence statement
for a in A:
    sigma_exists = sigma_exists or Qx
return sigma_exists
```

The initialization to false does make sense to me. In that we have not found an element in the set $A$ that has property $Qx$ before we start the loop and if the loop is empty or we don't find $Qx$ then we know no element in $A$ has property $Qx$. That makes sense to me. Note that the code just implements $\lor_{x \in A} Qx$. However, what I am not sure is if the algorithm/pseudo-code I wrote is indeed equivalent to $\sigma_{\exists} = \exists x (\varphi^A(x)\to Qx)$ and if that is the right interpretation. Is it?

Comment: It is $\exists x(\phi^A(x)\land Q(x))$, not $\to.$ The sentence $\lor_{x\in A}Q(x)$ is correct semantically, the usual FOL does not have indexed disjunctions like this.

Comment: speaking of which, recall our exchange here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992901/how-does-one-formally-show-that-bounded-search-with-some-property-ra-x-is-co

Comment: See [Restricted quantifier](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier) : $\exists x (x \in A \land Qx)$.

Comment: If we stay at the "standard" version of FOL, we have no $\in$ symbol; thus we have to use a predicaet $A(x)$ and thus : $\exists x (A(x) \land Q(x))$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I didn't realize it was the same as that exchange we had! Thats really useful thanks for that :) . I think then what still seems unclear to me is the dissymmetry of how we interpret $\forall x \in A: Qx$ formally with an implication but $\exists x \in A: Qx$ with a conjunction. I feel if I understand that then things should make a lot more sense to me. The dissymmetry is what confuses me.

Comment: @Pinocchio I think the key is realizing there's no reason at all to expect symmetry here. And then thinking carefully about the phrases. It's just about them expressing what is intended. (And to see that we should actually expect asymmetry at the outset, consider that restricting a universal quantifier should weaken the statement, whereas restricting an existential quantifier should strengthen it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$ is not a formula of FOL (unless you're viewing $A$ as a sort in which case I'd recommend against using $\in$). In particular, $\in$ is not part of the logical syntax of the framework of first-order logic. Instead, it is a binary predicate symbol in typical first-order theories of set theory.

Within the context of a suitable set theory, say ZFC, $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$ is often viewed as an abbreviation of $\exists x.x\in A\land Q(x)$ as suggested by spaceisdarkgreen.<sup>1</sup> There is no need to require a predicate corresponding to $x\in A$. On the other hand, using an $A$-indexed disjunction<sup>2</sup> isn't a valid FOL formula and just doesn't make sense. It mixes object-level and meta-leval notions. (There are infinitary logics which allow formulas *roughly like* this, but they tend to be poorly behaved and there is still a separation between object- and meta-level.)

Above, I was treating $A$ as a set (i.e. an individual) of the (set) theory. There are some other possibilities. Another possibility is that $A$ could be a class. In that case, $A$ is represented by some formula and $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$ would indeed mean $\exists x.\varphi^A(x)\land Q(x)$ where $\varphi^A$ is some formula that represents the class $A$. I, personally, don't like treating classes as set-like things and would rather talk only about representative formulas.

A third possibility, which I indicated in the first paragraph, is that $A$ is a sort. In that case, I'd prefer a notation like $\exists x\!:\!A.Q(x)$. There's typically no reason to do this unless you are working in a multi-sorted FOL. In this case, this is a primitive notion (or perhaps defined in terms of universal quantification over $A$), it is not an abbreviation for something else. In multi-sorted FOL, we simply have different quantifiers for each sort. Multi-sorted FOL won't have a predicate indicating "membership" in a sort, so there's nothing that corresponds to $x\in A$ or $\varphi^A$. (The [set-theoretic] semantics of multi-sorted FOL will assign a different "domain" set to each sort. In the semantics, $[\![\exists x:A.Q(x)]\!] = \boldsymbol{\exists} x\in [\![A]\!].[\![Q(x)]\!]$ where the brackets indicate the [overloaded] semantic mapping of sorts and formulas, and I use a slightly bolded $\boldsymbol{\exists}$ to distinguish between the object-level $\exists$ and the meta-level $\boldsymbol{\exists}$ in the semantics.)

As a final note, while you can (again) get some intuition by thinking about quantifiers as loops that check whether any/all "elements" satisfy the predicate in the body, there are a variety of ways where this view is inadequate. When you are not working in a set-theoretic context there may be no analogue to "elements", and even in a set-theoretic context it doesn't make sense to talk about "looping over" the elements of a set, e.g. the set of reals. You can, however, go the other way, and view certain loops as implementing *some* quantified formulas, but again this is a very special case that makes it harder to see the "essence" of quantification.

<sup>1</sup> Incidentally, you could derive this by using the definition of $\exists $ in terms of $\forall$, i.e. $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$ should be the same as $\neg\forall x\in A.\neg Q(x)$.

<sup>2</sup> While you can get some intuitions about $\forall$ and $\exists$ by viewing them (intuitively!) as (potentially infinite) conjunctions/disjunctions, I recommend care in doing so. While this intuition tends to be valid enough for classical logic, it doesn't generalize to non-classical logics. This means that there are aspects of the quantifiers that this intuition misses. It would be like considering quotients of groups but only considering commutative group examples; you lose the notion and significance of normality.

Comment: note I never said $x \in A$ was a formal FOL L-sentence/L-formula/L-term. It's not. I instead defined it via a definable set though for some reason you don't like that but thats the only way I know how to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: $x\in A$ *is* a formal formula in (typical) first-order theories of sets. It's $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$ that I was saying wasn't a formula of FOL itself, though you could easily make a slight extension of FOL to make it formal given a binary predicate symbol $\in$. It's not clear from your question what kind of thing you want $A$ to be. If you want $A$ to be a subset of some semantic domain, then that corresponds to the class case and using definable "sets". In this case, it really wouldn't make sense to have a *formal* notation $\exists x\in A.Q(x)$, though it's fine informally as you describe.

Comment: I don't know first-order theories of sets. Thats why I said $\exists x \in A: Qx $ was informal. What I had in mind as "formal" was FOL as described in these notes: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf. So for me $x \in A$ is short hand for "definable sets" i.e. set of elements that have $\mathcal A \models \varphi^A(x)$ in some L-structure $\mathcal A = (A;L)$.